# how to import dates in python

Tags: python, date, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe containg a column (dtype: object) in which dates are expressed as:

```
0    2014-11-07 14:08:00
1    2014-10-18 16:53:00
2    2014-10-27 11:57:00
3    2014-10-27 11:57:00
4    2014-10-08 16:35:00   
5    2014-10-24 16:36:00
6    2014-11-06 15:34:00
7    2014-11-11 10:30:00
8    2014-10-31 13:20:00
9    2014-11-07 13:15:00
10   2014-09-20 14:36:00
11   2014-11-07 17:21:00
12   2014-09-23 08:53:00
13   2014-11-05 09:37:00
14   2014-10-26 18:48:00
...
Name: ts_placed, Length: 13655, dtype: object
```

What i want to do is to read the column as dates and then split the dataset according to weeks.

What I tried to do is:

```
data["ts_placed"] = pd.to_datetime(data.ts_placed)
data.sort('ts_placed')
```

It did not work

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > datetime.datetime()
```

Does anybody know a way to import dates in pythons when these are expressed as objects?

Thank you very much

Comment: After the command `data["ts_placed"] = pd.to_datetime(data.ts_placed)`, maybe try `data["ts_placed"].head()` and post the exact output.

Comment: 0   2014-11-07 14:08:00
1   2014-10-18 16:53:00
2   2014-10-27 11:57:00
3   2014-10-27 11:57:00
4   2014-10-08 16:35:00
Name: ts_placed, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `to_datetime` doesn't work on a series. Looks like a vectorized version works:

```
data['ts_placed'] = [pd.to_datetime(strD) for strD in data.ts_placed]
data.sort('ts_placed')
```

**UPDATE** Wanted my accepted answer to match the figured solution from comments. So if the vectorized version of to_datetime is run it will not convert the vector to datatime objects if all of the strings cannot be converted. The version above will convert those that can be converted. In either case one should check whether all values have been converted.

Using the vectorized version one could check using:

```
data.ts_placed = pd.to_datetime(data.ts_placed)
if(not isinstance(data.ts_placed[0], pd.lib.Timestamp)):
    print 'Dates not converted correctly'
```

Using the manually vectorized version as above:

```
if(sum(not isinstance(strD, datetime.datetime) for strD in data.ts_placed) > 0):
    print 'Dates not converted correctly'
```

Comment: unfortunately i get another error:  TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(s)`, where `s` is a series, worked for me innumerable times.

Comment: Huh. Now I am actually getting the vectorized version to work. Does your  code work on the subset you have printed? Could there be an object that is not convert-able to datetime further down in the dataframe?

Comment: so it was. I had 13656 rows. I checked the excel file and two dates where in a different format. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `Series.dt` methods.

For the date, you can use `Series.dt.date`:

```
data['Date Column'] = data['Date Column'].dt.date
```

For the week, you can use `Series.dt.weekofyear` :

```
data['Week'] = data['Date Column'].dt.weekofyear
```

Then you would create new data based on week:

```
weekdata = data[data['Week'] == week number]
```

The `sort` should also work now.